# A "simple" surface-integral over the unit-sphere

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Calculate
$$
I=\iint_{x^2+y^2+z^2=1}{e^{x-y} \mathbb{d}S}
$$

---

Parameterization is not helpful:
$$
I=\int_0^{2\pi}{\mathbb{d}\varphi\int_0^\pi{e^{\sin\theta(\cos\varphi-\sin\varphi)}\sin\theta\mathbb{d}\theta}}
$$
... nor is transformation to standard double-integral:
$$
I=\int_{-1}^1{\mathbb{d}x\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^\sqrt{1-x^2}{\frac{e^{x-y}}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}\mathbb{d}y}}
$$

Comment: small trivial point but there is a mixing of $\varphi$ and $\phi$ in your first transformed integral.

Comment: @Kevin I'm accustomed to using $\varphi$ here. What's the difference?

Comment: I guess there is no difference, you can use either, as long as you choose only one :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It helps to carry out the $\phi$ integral first,
$$I=\int_0^\pi \sin\theta\,d\theta\,\int_0^{2\pi} \,e^{\sin\theta(\cos\varphi-\sin\varphi)}\,d\phi$$
$$\qquad\qquad=2\pi\int_0^\pi   I_0\left(\sqrt{2}\sin\theta\right)\,\sin\theta\,d\theta=2^{3/2}  \pi  \sinh \sqrt{2}.$$

Comment: Sorry, what does the $I_0$ notation mean? Your result is correct :)

Comment: it's a Bessel function

Comment: Just to compare: the command of Maple `VectorCalculus:-SurfaceInt(exp(x - y), [x, y, z] = Sphere(<0, 0, 0>, 1))` reduces it to the integral  $$\int_{0}^{2\,\pi}\!\pi\,{{I}_{1}\left(\cos \left( \theta \right) -
\sin \left( \theta \right) \right)}+\pi\,{{\rm \bf L}_{1}\left(\cos
 \left( \theta \right) -\sin \left( \theta \right) \right)}+2\,{\rm d}
\theta,
 $$ where ${\rm \bf L}_1$ is a Struve function and $I_1$ is a Bessel function.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Thanks! I'm wondering if there's any elementary solution that sees no use of special functions.

Comment: And you may replace from the beginning $y-x$ in the exponent with $\sqrt2 x$ via a rotation.

Comment: @PietroMaier: Making use of your valuable comment, the command of Maple `VectorCalculus:-SurfaceInt(exp(z*sqrt(2)), [x, y, z] = Sphere(<0, 0, 0>, 1))`  results in $\sqrt {2} \left( {{\rm e}^{2\,\sqrt {2}}}-1 \right) {{\rm e}^{-\sqrt {
2}}}\pi
$. This coinsides with the result done by hand.